# Want to iterate through this array of objects i am bringing back from facebook Graph Api - Oauth2.0

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array, oauth-2.0, iteration

```
    $education = $user->education;

    Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [school] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 112629628784911 [name] => Vardhman Shiksha Mandir ) [year] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 136328419721520 [name] => 2009 ) [type] => High School ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [school] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 115934828416686 [name] => jamia hamdrad ) [concentration] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 187549374618419 [name] => B.Tech Computer Science ) ) [type] => College ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [school] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 133233016699548 [name] => Hamdard University ) [type] => College [classes] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 196267900399898 [name] => 2nd year [with] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 553736429 [name] => Ahmed Abdul Zahra ) ) [from] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 553736429 [name] => Ahmed Abdul Zahra ) ) ) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [school] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 104008189635968 [name] => Jamia Hamdard ) [year] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 138879996141011 [name] => 2013 ) [type] => Graduate School ) )
```

i have tried iterating it with nested foreach loops..

```
     foreach($education as $educationFirstArray){
     foreach($educationFirstArray as $educationSecondArray){
        foreach($educationSecondArray as $key=>$value){
         echo "<strong>".$key."</strong> -> ".$value."<br/>";
        }
     }
   }
```

Output:

```
 id -> 112629628784911
 name -> Vardhman Shiksha Mandir
 id -> 136328419721520
 name -> 2009

 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in index.php on line 73
  id -> 115934828416686
   name -> jamia hamdrad

 Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in     index.php on line 74
```

Any Help with getting this array above iterated will be highly appreciable, Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to provide a proper print out and for-each part of code.

Comment: @qeremy: I have made it presentable as a question and added the for-each part of the code and the output as well, i am really fighting with it. Just hope that you will now look into this question.. Cheers.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I must say that this data structure is very complicated. Arrays or objects in a mess. Anyway..

I think you need a recursive function that loops over all data structure, simply;

```
function looper($input) {
    foreach ($input as $key => $val) {
        // control here
        if (is_array($val) || is_object($val)) {
            looper($val);
        } else {
            printf("%s -> %s\n", $key, $val);
        }
    }
}

// call
looper($education);
```

Output;

```
id -> 112629628784911
name -> Vardhman Shiksha Mandir
id -> 136328419721520
name -> 2009
type -> High School
id -> 115934828416686
name -> jamia hamdrad
id -> 187549374618419
name -> B.Tech Computer Science
type -> College
id -> 133233016699548
name -> Hamdard University
type -> College
id -> 196267900399898
name -> 2nd year
id -> 553736429
name -> Ahmed Abdul Zahra
id -> 553736429
name -> Ahmed Abdul Zahra
id -> 104008189635968
name -> Jamia Hamdard
id -> 138879996141011
name -> 2013
type -> Graduate School
```

And here is a simulation of your data structure which gives the same print out of your own;

```
$education = array(
    (object) array(
        'school' => (object) array('id' => '112629628784911', 'name' => 'Vardhman Shiksha Mandir'),
        'year' => (object) array('id' => '136328419721520', 'name' => '2009'),
        'type' => 'High School'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'school' => (object) array('id' => '115934828416686', 'name' => 'jamia hamdrad'),
        'concentration' => array(
            (object) array('id' => '187549374618419', 'name' => 'B.Tech Computer Science')
        ),
        'type' => 'College'
    ),
    (object) array(
        'school' => (object) array('id' => '133233016699548', 'name' => 'Hamdard University'), 
        'type' => 'College', 
        'classes' => array (
            (object) array('id' => '196267900399898', 'name' => '2nd year', 
                'with' => array((object) array('id' => 553736429, 'name' => 'Ahmed Abdul Zahra')),
                'from' => (object) array('id' => 553736429, 'name' => 'Ahmed Abdul Zahra')
            )
        )
    ),
    (object) array(
        'school' => (object) array('id' => '104008189635968', 'name' => 'Jamia Hamdard'),
        'year' => (object) array('id' => '138879996141011', 'name' => 2013),
        'type' => 'Graduate School'
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a great answer! Totally solved my problem, thanks a lot for helping me out. I must say this is my first question on **Stackoverflow**, it's truly a pleasure having you @qeremy. Thanks bro.